# How to convert the phone number to words in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

**I need to convert the phone number to words in Kotlin like 0266215972 = zero two six six two one five nine seven two**

Comment: Ok, so what did you try?

Comment: If I define a variable like this
val PhoneNum: String = "0266215972"
How do I write code for PhoneNum to become words?

Comment: The question is clear enough. However, on this site we expect people to make an effort, demonstrate that effort in their question, and describe the concrete problem they're struggling with. Just dumping your requirements and expecting a solution leads to downvotes and close votes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I will improve myself thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can just create an array of words and map the individual numbers to that:

```
fun main() {
    val words = arrayOf("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
            "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine")
    val phone = "0266215972"
    val result = phone.map { words[it.toString().toInt()] }.joinToString(" ")
    
    println(result) // "zero two six six two one five nine seven two"
}
```

Comment: As a rule, I don't answer zero effort questions, but I'm making one exception today because 'tis the season :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I just learned Kotlin. I'm not very good at coding. But I want to try writing code. I'll try even more. Anyway, thank you :)